# Recommended method for recognising protocols in python?

Tags: python, sockets, protocols, jython-2.7

I have a quick (Hopefully) easy question. I just want to know what the easiest way is to recognising (in python code) a protocol like SNMTP or SSH. Or is there an other way to identify a protocol. I'm not that familiar with programming so hopefully my question is clear enough to understand. I'm trying to build an network sniffer

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense unless you include what you are trying to do. Are you building a network sniffer? A client? A server?

Comment: Oh yes of course . I'm trying to build a network sniffer, but the first thing i want to do is recognise/identify a protocol @BurhanKhalid

Answer (score -1):

urlparse
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse

```
from urlparse import urlparse
o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
print o.scheme
http
```

It will works for any another protocol defined in url like a 
postgresql://user:password@host:port/database
in example

Comment: The **scheme** is not the same as the protocol; otherwise it would say protocol.